# Eclipse Android SDK cannot see new Samsung Galaxy S4 device via a USB connection

Tags: android, eclipse, usb, samsung-mobile

Using Eclipse (Juno SR2) with all the latest updates for Android (ADT plugin v21.1.0) cannot see the new Galaxy S4 as an available device via the USB connection.

Per the Samsung website the correct driver software is "Samsung_USB_Driver_for_Mobile_Phones_v1.5.14.0.ext" (which happens to be the same driver that I have been successfully using with a Samsung Note for the past 18 months).

Even when I go to a command prompt and type "adb.exe devices" to list the connected devices the list is empty.

From within the GS4 I have enabled the allow "unknown sources" for installation of applications, though the "allow debug" checkbox doesn't seem to be included anymore.

Interestingly enough, Windows Explorer does show the handset just fine and I am able to surf the device from Windows.

Any suggestions on how to make Eclipse/Android ADB see the device?

Comment: Have you installed usb driver for your device?

Comment: i had a similar issue with my samsung galaxy s2.  Installing samsung kies solved this issue for me.

Comment: For those who need the driver mentioned in the post (*Samsung_USB_Driver_for_Mobile_Phones_v1.5.14.0.ext*), you can get it from http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SGH-I747MBBATT, the Downloads tab. It works with Galaxy S4 just fine.

Comment: This video may be useful to answer your question: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X6FkhSeiYd8

Comment: @Voicu: Thank you for the link to the driver -- adb on my host PC couldn't see my Galaxy S4 until I downloaded and ran that EXE file.

Comment: @Voicu Later I found the (same?) driver http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-sdks/Samsung-Andorid-USB-Driver-for-Windows .

Answer (score 105, accepted):

> From within the GS4 I have enabled the allow "unknown sources" for installation of applications, though the "allow debug" checkbox doesn't seem to be included anymore.

It should be in Developer Options. If your device is running Android 4.2, Developer Options is hidden by default. To enable it:

- Go into Settings > About
- Tap on the Build Number entry seven times (`Toast`s will appear to help you keep count)
- Press BACK, and Developer Options should be in the Settings list

Comment: You da' man!  How did you find that?  If it were possible I'd up-vote you even more.

Comment: @CirrusFlyer: "How did you find that?" -- it is scattered in various places, such as: http://developer.android.com/tools/index.html ("On Android 4.2 and higher, the Developer options screen is hidden by default. To make it available, go to Settings > About phone and tap Build number seven times. Return to the previous screen to find Developer options.")

Comment: R U god @CommonsWare? Saved a lot of time.

Comment: This is insane... worked for me too, though I think I tapped the wrong thing (Android 4.4.2). No Toasts appeared and I think I had to tap it more than 7 times, but eventually I got big white K that rotated randomly when i tapped it. After tapping it about 5 times red screen with text Android appeared. After I backed out I was in the developer settings. Where the hell do they come up with these things?! (This method grants you one time access to the settings, but the settings do not appear on the menus).

Comment: @TimoLehto: "Where the hell do they come up with these things?" -- what you described is non-standard, so you would have to ask your device manufacturer or ROM mod author.

Answer (score 0):

You may use an old version of adb.exe. Update platform-tools.
You may have to set a new path to adb.exe as well.

Answer (score 0):

This answer may be outdated. But adding it for the benefit of other users. If you are using say S5, you may need to download the specific driver from samsungs website - http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SM-G900AZWAATT

After a lot of search/stackoverflow, found the thing that worked for me.

Comment: oh yeah! its worked for me, thank you. Samsung Galaxy S4 USB Driver updated http://www.samsung.com/levant/support/model/GT-I9500ZKAMID